# matlab function with argument not required

Tags: matlab

I create a function

```
function y = getValue(modelName, param, option)
    open_system(modelName);
    runModel(option);
    y = getActiveFun(param);
end
```

I would like when calling this function to have the choice to pass or not argument `option`
from some other files I call the function with all arguments and sometimes I would like to call it without passing `option` argument ?

I would like to call : `getValue(modelName, param)` from other files

How could I do that ?

Comment: What would you expect `runModel` to do if you don't pass the `option` parameter ?

Comment: I would like to call : getValue(modelName,param) from other files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `nargin` variable:

```
function y = getValue(modelName,param,option)
    open_system(modelName);

    if (nargin < 3)
        # No option passed, do something like
        runModel('defaultOption')
    else
        # Option passed
        runModel(option);
    end
    y = getActiveFun(param);
end
```

`nargin` is just the number of input arguments that were actually submitted. Thus, `nargin == 3` indicates that the option parameter has been set, `nargin < 3` that it has not been set.

Thus, you could now always call your function like

```
result = getValue('myModel', myParameter)
```

or with all parameters

```
result = getValue('myModel', myParameter, someOption)
```

Comment: I would like to call : getValue(modelName,param) from other files (without passing option to the getValue function

Comment: And that is exactly what the code above allows you to do. In case you do not pass option, you will have to decide how to call 'runModel' then. I added a dummy default option, but you can handle that however you like.

Answer (score 2):

While solutions with `nargin` are already given and more or less a standard usage within most MATLAB codebases, I think there is a nicer alternative that is more readable.

With `nargin` in big functions, you have to remember what argument 3 was exactly. Especially if you have more optional arguments, it becomes cumbersome to keep track or to allow that some optional arguments are passed, while others are not.

The first and easier solution is my personal alternative to `nargin`, and that is using the `exist` function:

```
function [output] = getValue(modelName,param,option, otherOption)

if ~exist('option', 'var') || isempty(option)
  option = 'defaultValueForOption';
end

if ~exist('otherOption', 'var') || isempty(otherOption)
  otherOption = 'defaultValueForOption';
end

% perform other actions
```

The advantage is that now all input-related code is at the beginning and it is more verbose as to what should be happening. You won't clutter your other code with that logic. And you can also supplement those `if` statements with validation of the input and fall back onto the default when an invalid option is given.

The other possibility is standard in later versions of MATLAB: the [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html) class. With this class, you can define even more complicated scenarios of optional parameters and even key-value pairs.

Below is a self-descriptive example I have kept to avoid needing the documentation every time.

```
%% Usage Example input Parser
%
function output = FuncName(rParam1, rParam2, oParam1, oParam2, varargin)

p = inputParser();

defaultValue = 0;
validatorFunc = @(x)(true); % validator function should return true when x is valid

%% Input Format definition

p.addRequired('rParam1', validatorFunc);
p.addRequired('rParam2', validatorFunc);

p.addOptional('oParam1', defaultValue, validatorFunc);
p.addOptional('oParam2', defaultValue, validatorFunc);

p.addParamValue('kvParam1', defaultValue, validatorFunc);
p.addParamValue('kvParam2', defaultValue, validatorFunc);
p.addParamValue('kvParam3', defaultValue, validatorFunc);
p.addParamValue('kvParam4', defaultValue, validatorFunc)

%% Optional Settings
% expand supplied struct to ParamValue pairs (or other arguments)
p.StructExpand = true; % default: false

%% Parse
p.parse(rParam1, rParam2, oParam1, oParam2, varargin{:})

%% Retrieve results
values = p.Results(); % structure with all values
defaultedArgs = p.UsingDefaults; % cell array of all parameter names using defaults
end
```

This approach is even more verbose and personally, I don't quite like the fact that one has to redefine for every input whether it is required or optional and that it requires quite a lot of boilerplate code. But at least, it is a solution that is a standard solution and without a doubt to be preferred for larger functions.

Both approaches do suffer from a drawback compared to the `nargin` way of checking: they are both slower. So if you use these in functions that get called a lot (or only perform a very quick calculaion), it might be more worthwhile to use `nargin` instead.

Comment: This example code does not work: `p.expandStruct = true;` should be `p.StructExpand = true;`. Source: [inputParser docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html)

Comment: @BrandonJackson: thanks for letting me know, I've adapted my example.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, lets see the basics ([see documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)).

In a function if an argument is not used, it is only a "programming warning", nothing more. So the problem is that you use a parameter that may or may not be provided.

So this is handled using

```
nargin                  % the number of parameters provided in current call

nargin(function_name)   % the number of parameters the declaration has
```

So based on these you may program some conditions and include there the code that uses the non-standard input parameters.

For more complex cases [varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) is most proper that handles variable length parameter list where the ordering may not be defined. But this is too much for this question

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following link:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/65943

they have several suggestions